# Error when installing matcaps

Tags: interface, error

Tried installing matcaps from older blender version. Here's the info log. What can be the problem here? [image]

Comment: Looks like a permission issue. Only the administrator can make modifications to `C:\\Program Files`.

Comment: Yep, it was, thank you. Did it manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Windows you need to be an Administrator (or run a program as administrator) in order to modify `C:\Program Files`. Your problem can be solved by logging in as a user who is an administrator and manually copy the files to the `C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.81\datafiles\studio\studiolights\matcap` directory.

Comment: You could also run Blender as administrator and repeat the procedure, however that's generally not recommended for security reasons.